# How to use the fluent api to set a foreign key in EF 6

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

In EF 6, how can I specify that an entity's property is a foreign key reference, such that the entity being referenced cannot be removed if it is a parent in another entity?

Here is my class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("parentId")]
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class, the `parentId` is a reference to another `User`.

Here is my current code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(x => x.id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional<User>(x => x.user);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> DataService.Context.User_user: : Multiplicity conflicts with the
>   referential constraint in Role 'User_user_Target' in relationship
>   'User_user'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are
>   non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Answer (score 1):

Maped to the navigation property, you should add virtual property of type User than map to:

```
public class User 
{
 [Key] public int id { get; set; }     
 public int UserId { get; set; }
 public virtual User User{get;set;}
}
// ...
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional<User>(x=> x.User);
```

Read more about relation-ships [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

Comment: I am getting the following error: 'DataService.Models.User' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'DataService.Models.User' could be found

Comment: Does the virtual User change the database structure at all?

Comment: No it used in EF model only.

Comment: Hope it's held you. If yes please make it as answer

Comment: I am getting the following error: The property 'UserId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: Move [ForeignKey("UserId")] above the User navigation property, not the UserId field.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit. The foreign key needs to be called parentId.